# How can I entirely disable browser media integration in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: browser, media-player, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace, vivaldi

I'm using a fully updated KDE Neon, currently with KDE Plasma 5.16.3. Using Vivaldi as a web browser.

Plasma has a feature that allows you to control in-browser media players (such as YouTube, but not only) in the same way you control media player applications: Using desktop widgets, keyboard buttons etc.

The above is normally implemented as a browser extension, working with a plugin for the Plasma environment.

I want to disable this feature, but surprisingly I'm unable to do it. I've removed the extension from Vivaldi and I've also removed the `plasma-browser-integration` package from my system but still, both widgets and my keyboard's play/pause buttons work on videos playing in the browser.

How is the feature still working? What can I do to disable it?

Answer (score -1):

The [wiki](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Browser_Integration#How_to_install) gives a hint at how to activate this feature for common browsers. The answer is then to disable or remove the browser extension.

Comment: Except that this doesn't work, as I said in the original post…